# remove doesn't delete a entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, model-view-controller

I'm creating a web application and I have a Little issue.
I googled already a lot but couldn't find the right answer for me.

I Want to delete a entity out of the DB, with the entity manager .remove method.
The weird thing is, every other method works except for the delete method.

Thanks in advance.

one of my models:

```
package nl.****.deploy.****.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OrderBy;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "STAGES", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"NAME", "APPLICATION_ID"}) )
@SequenceGenerator(name="STAGES_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)

public class Stage extends DomainObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = ******;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "STAGES_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SORT_KEY", nullable = false)
    private Integer sortKey;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATION_ID", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private ApplicationInfo application;

    @OrderBy("sortKey ASC")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "stage")
    private Set<Environment> environments;


    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ApplicationInfo getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public void setApplication(ApplicationInfo application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public Set<Environment> getEnvironments() {
        return environments;
    }

    public void setEnvironments(Set<Environment> environments) {
        this.environments = environments;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DomainObject obj) {

        if (obj instanceof Stage) {
            return this.sortKey.compareTo(((Stage) obj).getSortKey());
        } else {
            return super.compareTo(obj);
        }

    }

    public Integer getSortKey() {
        return sortKey;
    }

    public void setSortKey(Integer sortKey) {
        this.sortKey = sortKey;
    }


}
```

Service:

```
package nl.****.deploy.****.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import nl.****.deploy.****.dao.StageDao;
import nl.****.deploy.****.model.Stage;
import nl.****.deploy.****.service.StageService;

@Service

public class StageServiceImpl implements StageService {

    @Autowired
    private StageDao StageDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Stage load(Long stageId) {
        return StageDao.find(stageId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveStage(Stage stage) {
        StageDao.save(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Stage stage) {
        StageDao.delete(stage);
    }

}
```

And my baseDao, what I call from all my other dao's

```
package nl.****.deploy.****.dao.impl;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import nl.****.deploy.****.dao.BaseDao;
import nl.****.deploy.****.model.DomainObject;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T extends DomainObject> implements BaseDao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<T> domainObjectClass;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public BaseDaoImpl() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        domainObjectClass = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public T save(T t) {
        if (t.getId() == null) {
            getEntityManager().persist(t);
        } else {
            t = getEntityManager().merge(t);
        }
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void delete(T t) {
        if (!getEntityManager().contains(t)) {
            t = getEntityManager().merge(t);
        }
        getEntityManager().remove(t);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(getDomainObjectClass(), id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> cq = builder.createQuery(getDomainObjectClass());
        Root<T> root = cq.from(getDomainObjectClass());
        cq.select(root);
        return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    protected Class<T> getDomainObjectClass() {
        return domainObjectClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: No I don't need a commit due hybernate, I'm sure that isn't the problem.
The other methods work properally so it should work without.
@sidgate

Comment: Instead of reinventing the generic dao I sugest the use of Spring Data JPA (and throw away your own one). Your problem is due to the fact your service isn't transactional (the delete method isn't) and as that should be your transactional layer nothing is going to happen.

Comment: Your right at the transactional part, thanks.
But I did have that in other services and they're delete funtion doesn't work to.
And before I'm going to do your suggestion I want to wait a bit longer.
Because it has to work this way.
But thanks @M.Deinum

Comment: No it hasn't has to work this way, without a transaction modifying data won't work that goes for updates/deletes/inserts. Also having the transactional on the dao is / might be dangerous especially in wrongly specified service methods (imagine a missing `@Transactional` on the service and yo have 3 dao calls which leads to 3 separate transactions).

Comment: Well the update method(save) works fine and your true at the part where I can get more transactions but I checked that already and it was only at that delete function were I forgot the annotation.@M.Deinum